# How to detect if a file is encoded using mp3PRO?

Tags: audio, hex, mp3, file-format

I have a folder which contains lot of MP3 files, some of them are encoded using [mp3PRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3PRO).

Since this format is now obsolete, I'd like to convert them back to MP3 (converters can be found easily).

**Is there is a way to detect programatically if a file is encoded using mp3PRO format ?** (eg : by looking at file header or specific signatures using an hex editor)

The [official player](http://www.mp3prozone.com/download.htm) is able to detect if file is encoded using mp3PRO  (the logo is highlighted or not) so I suppose this is technically possible.

What I found so far is that bitrate of mp3PRO file appears to be pretty low (50% of non encoded file) : eg : a 128 kbps file will appears as 64kbps. However a 320 kbps file will appears as 160 kpbs (which are pretty common) so it cannot be used as a rule.

Comment: vlc handles it, so check the vlc source to see what they do to detect the format.

Comment: Do you mean one by one ? or is there a way to do that for a list of files ?

Comment: VLC might decode it as base mp3 file. What do you see under Tools->Codec Information, when you play it with vlc?

Comment: Something very similar to as any MP3 file : Steam 0 Type : Audio Codec : MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mpga) Channels : Stereo Sample rate : 22050 Hz Bitrate : 64kbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found out and how I fixed it. I wrote in here in case somebody would need it :

MP3Pro files does not contains any special flag in the mp3 header that would help to recognize them.

They are technically very similar to usual mp3 files, except they are encoded half the bit and sample rate (eg : a 128kpbs 44100hz file will be encoded as a 64kps 22050hz file, resulting in mp3pro file being approx half the size of original file).

This has been made for compatibility, so default players can play them without any change.

They also contains some SBR data, which allow to synthetically rebuild the lost audio part (high frequencies) and to play them it was before the mp3 pro conversion.

Detecting the SBR data seems very hard if not impossible : it would require to decode the actual mp3 frames. Also there is no documentation to be found about mp3pro format.

What I did (which works but required some manual effort) : **I added all files to be checked to playlist of an mp3 player (foobar 2000 in my case) then sorted the files on the sample rate column : most 22050 hz mp3 files were indeed mp3 pro files.**

They were converted back to mp3 using winamp + the mp3pro plugin made for it, available here : http://www.wav-mp3.com/mp3pro-to-mp3.htm

Answer (score 0):

Someone actually has a patent on doing this.

https://patents.google.com/patent/US7334176B2/en?oq=7334176

It involves looking at the ancillary data and calculating CRCs, and it was more than I cared to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linux/Cygwin tool `file` to display the sample rate.  If the MP3 was ripped from a CD, then it will be 44.1 kHz, but if it is MP3Pro, it will report at 22.05 kHz.

```
file '001_Air Liquide - First Piece Of Evidence.mp3'
001_Air Liquide - First Piece Of Evidence.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, \
  contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo

file 'Air Liquide - First Piece Of Evidence MP3Pro.mp3'
Air Liquide - First Piece Of Evidence MP3Pro.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, \
  contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v2,  96 kbps, 22.05 kHz, JntStereo
```

You can use `grep` to decide.  I'm working on a python script to convert thousands of files, by automating Winamp 2.95 and the official Thompson MP3 decoder, and the `lame` to reencode.  A long time ago, I ripped all of my CD collection as mp3pro, and it's time to fix that.